# Ruby - Parse txt file to json

Tags: ruby

how should I parse a txt file with the below format to read it as json in ruby?

Thank you.

```
{"sales": "52,000,000", "id": 12, "comp_name": "FriedFood"}
{"sales": "51,000,000", "id": 1, "comp_name": "Copley"}
{"sales": "54,000,000", "id": 2, "comp_name": "tony's"}
{"sales": "52,000,789", "id": 3, "comp_name": "J&J"}
```

Comment: I've tried different things and insisted on creating an array for every line of the File I was reading. I was not able however to create 4 arrays (one for each line).

Answer (score 2):

Read the file as JSON

```
require "json"
lines = File.open("filename.txt").read.split("}\n").join("},")+"}"
data = JSON.parse([lines].to_s)
```

**Update**:
This is an explanation of the code.

The `parse` function accept JSON string. In the example there are new lines, after each JSON object.

The functions `split("}\n").join("}")` will remove the new lines from the txt file string. After that you need to add `}` to close the JSON file.

Finally, all these objects should be sorted in an array to create a valid JSON file - `[lines].to_s`

Comment: Please explain your conversion steps. Why do you have to `split` and `join`, append `"}"` and call `[...].to_s` in order to `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: @Stefan The txt file isn't a valid JSON, see the update on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Parse each line as a JSON object, like this:

```
require 'json'
items = File.open('tmp.json', 'r').each_line.map { |l| JSON.parse(l) }
puts items.to_s
```

Edit: modified to use map, based on the comment below.

Comment: Perhaps `f = File.open('filename', 'r').each_line.map { |l| JSON.parse(l) }` (and drop `items = []`), or, if the file is not large, `IO.readlines('filename').map { |l| JSON.parse(l) }` .

Comment: or `items = IO.foreach('filename').map { |l| JSON.parse(l) }`

Comment: BTW, `puts` will call `to_s` if the argument is not a string so you don't have to convert it yourself

Comment: Stefan, when `puts` is called with an array argument, it [prints each value on a new line](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts).  I call `to_s` first, (alias for `inspect` on arrays), just to make the output look more list-like.  Just a personal preference of mine.